# Dynamic fields having issue saving to DB through endpoint

Tags: reactjs

i have issue saving this through the endpoint when i tried to get this done specifying null on each models fields in the backend the rest of the code works fine, but this particular area of the code dynamic fields isn't save to database, Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const [inputField, setInputFields] = useState([
    {vin:'', year:'', make:'', model:'', vtype:'', qty:'', color:'', plate:'', lot:'', 
    vstate:'', info:''}
 ])

 const handleChangeInput= (index, event) => {
   const values = [...inputField]
   values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
   setInputFields(values)
   console.log(index, values)
  }

 const handleAddField = () => {
   const newFields ={vin:'', year:'', make:'', model:'', vtype:'', qty:'', color:'', 
   plate:'', lot:'', vstate:'', info:''}
   setInputFields([...inputField, newFields])
 }

 const handleRemoveField = (index) => {
     const values = [...inputField];
     values.splice(index, 1);
    setInputFields(values);
 }


 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const postData = {
      vin: inputField.vin, year: inputField.year, make: inputField.make, 
      model: inputField.model, vtype: inputField.vtype, qty: inputField.qty, 
      color: inputField.color, plate: inputField.plate, lot: inputField.lot, 
      vstate: inputField.vstate, info: inputField.info, 
    }
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data = console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

this is the part for the jsx

```
    {inputField.map((inputField, index) => (

                    <div key={index} className="card-body">

                      <div className="col-sm-12">
                          <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="inputVin"></label>
                            <input 
                              type="text" 
                              id="inputVin" 
                              value={inputField.vin}
                              placeholder="Vin Number" 
                              className="form-control" 
                              name="vin"
                              onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                            />
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-2">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputYear"></label>
                              <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="inputYear" 
                                placeholder="* Year" 
                                value={inputField.year}
                                className="form-control" 
                                name="year"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputMake"></label>
                              <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="inputMake" 
                                placeholder="* Make" 
                                value={inputField.make}
                                className="form-control" 
                                name="make"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                              />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputModel"></label>
                              <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="inputModel" 
                                placeholder="* Model" 
                                className="form-control" 
                                value={inputField.model}
                                name="model"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                              />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputType"></label>
                              <select 
                                id="inputType" 
                                value={inputField.vtype}
                                className="form-control custom-select"
                                name="vtype"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                                >
                                <option selected disabled>Select Vehicle Type</option>
                                <option value="ATV">ATV</option>
                                <option value="Boat">Boat</option>
                                <option value="Car">Car</option>
                                <option value="Heavy-Equipment">Heavy Equipment</option>
                                <option value="Large-Yatch">Large Yatch</option>
                                <option value="MotorCycle">MotorCycle</option>
                                <option value="Pickup">Pickup</option>
                                <option value="RV">RV</option>
                                <option value="SUV">SUV</option>
                                <option value="Trailer">Trailer</option>
                                <option value="Van">Van</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-1">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputQty"></label>
                              <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="inputQty" 
                                placeholder="Qty" 
                                value={inputField.qty}
                                className="form-control" 
                                name="qty"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                              />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>

                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputColor"></label>
                              <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="inputColor" 
                                placeholder="Vehicle Color" 
                                value={inputField.color}
                                className="form-control" 
                                name="color"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                              />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputPlate"></label>
                              <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="inputPlate" 
                                placeholder="Plate Licence" 
                                value={inputField.plate}
                                className="form-control" 
                                name="plate"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                              />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputLot"></label>
                              <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="inputLot" 
                                placeholder="Lot Number" 
                                value={inputField.lot}
                                className="form-control" 
                                name="lot"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                              />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <label htmlFor="inputState"></label>
                              <select 
                                id="inputState" 
                                className="form-control custom-select"
                                value={inputField.vstate}
                                name="vstate"
                                onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                                >
                                <option selected disabled>State & Province</option>
                                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>                      

                      </div>

                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="inputInfo">Additional Vehicle Information</label>
                        <textarea 
                          id="inputInfo" 
                          className="form-control" 
                          rows={4}
                          value={inputField.info} 
                          name="info"
                          onChange={event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div className="form-group col-2 float-right">
                        { index > 0 ?
                          <button 
                            type="button" 
                            onClick={() => handleRemoveField(index)}
                            className="form-control btn btn-danger"
                            >
                              Remove
                            </button>
                            :
                            ""
                        }
                      </div>


                    </div>
                ))}
```

Comment: Would help if you include exact error message. But as far as I can see,`inputField` looks like an array, yet in `handleSubmit` you access it as if it is an object - should already cause errors here

Comment: Yes it is an array, dynamic form. So tell me anyway to access it different from what i have there, yes is a list, maybe that could be the solution ..the exact error is 400 , and I already specified it. Thank you data is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think this is a syntax error

> 

```
.then(data = console.log(data)) ---> .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Would try it out...thanks

Comment: it works but seems the array wasn't captured as per my initial request to the api call.. anyway around this still from the above data

Comment: Why have you declared the input field state as an array? Why not an object?

Comment: I will try that out, the implementation is to add additional form by clicking add field would extract that out and put it in a form object...but let me know if you have other approach just a simple example